# Hiding an embedded window/control

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am trying to hide an embedded advertisement window inside of AOL. Here is a picture of the window/control I'm trying to hide:

[image]

This window/control is a child of the chat room window.

Here is the code I am currently trying to use:

```
    public static void hideAdvertisement()
    {
        IntPtr hWND = AOL.FindWindow("AOL Frame25", null);
        IntPtr child = AOL.FindWindowEx(hWND, (IntPtr)null, "MDIClient", null);
        IntPtr chatRoom = AOL.FindWindowEx(child, (IntPtr)null, "AOL Child", null);
        IntPtr advertisementParent = AOL.FindWindowEx(chatRoom, (IntPtr)null, "ATL:69F46668", null);
        IntPtr advertisement = AOL.FindWindowEx(advertisementParent, (IntPtr)null, "Internet Explorer_Server", null);
        long style = AOL.GetWindowLong(advertisement, -16);
        style &= ~(0x10000000L);
        style &= ~(0x00040000L);
        AOL.ShowWindow(advertisement, 0);
        AOL.SetWindowLong(advertisement, -16, (int)style);
        AOL.ShowWindow(advertisement, 5);
        AOL.ShowWindow(advertisement, 0);
    }
```

I am absolutely sure I have the right handles for the control. I can see the messages being sent in Spy++.

Along with the code above, I have tried other things too.

Let me be clear that `ShowWindow(handle, 0); (SW_HIDE)` is NOT working for me. Any thoughts?